# combobox focus on beginning of text after selection

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm using winforms with a combobox that has a wider drop down width than it's size. when a user selects something from there, it displays just the ending of the text instead of the beginning. how do i default it to show text starting with the start of the string?

ie. combobox has items

- Atlanta Georgia
- Athens Georgia
- Miami Florida
- ....

and the user picks one and all they see in the box afterwards is "a Georgia"

no, i unfortunately don't have the realestate to make the combobox bigger, and the order of the words in the list won't be changed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to call the select *after* the SelectedIndexChanged event happens:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { comboBox1.Select(0, 0); }));
}
```

Comment: Sure enough.  Nice one!

Comment: Nice! Just a sidenote... Depending on where you attach your EventHandler, the window handle might not have been created yet. In which case, you can just do an if check. `if(this.IsHandleCreated){ this.BeginInvoke(etc...);}`

Answer (score 2):

Select position zero by force:

```
comboBox1.Select(0, 0);
```

...after the selection is complete and locked in, just call `Select`.

You could also use:

```
comboBox1.SelectAll();
```

...if you want it all highlighted.

Comment: looks promising, but can't get it to work. Have tried using Selected Index Changed, Selection Change Committed and Validated. None of them seem to make it happen after a user selects something from the list, just when the form first loads.

Comment: figured out a way to get yours to work, putting it in as an Edit. Thanks for helping out.